# How to make a list of values from an array (2 columns) based on one criteria?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, arraylist

I have the following array:

```
ID        Chat nr
           #N/A
126551829   33
126554922   33
126555078   33
126555079   33
126555261   33
126555278   33
126553808   34
126553820   34
126554425   35
126555786   36
126555925   36
126555944   36
126556297   37
126556298   37
126556299   37
126556300   37
126556307   37
126556320   37
126556322   37
126556323   37
126556323   37
126556323   37
126556323   37
126556325   37
126556332   37
           #N/A
           #N/A
           #N/A
etc...
```

This data is found in a sheet named "Import". In a sheet named "Dashboard" I have drop down list where the users of the sheet can choose a chat nr. If the user for example chooses 36, I want the following output (IDs) from this macro:

```
126555786   
126555925   
126555944
```

I have tried to make a code, but my code returns all the values from the array, and not only the ones with "36". Further, I have formulas in the column for chat numbers in the "Import" sheet.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim xRng As Range
Dim xLastRow As Long
Dim xLastRow2 As Long
Dim i As Integer
On Error Resume Next

Set xRng = Worksheets("Import").Range(Range("B18"))
If xRng(, 2).Value = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B9").Value Then
xRng.Copy Range("F6")
xLastRow = xRng.Rows.Count + 1
ActiveSheet.Range("F6:F" & xLastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End If

End Sub
```

Explanation of the cells in the code:

- B18 contains the name of the array. I need to do this indirectly.
- B9 contains the chat nr I want to show (in this example, 36)
- F6 is the first output cell in the output range. I want this range to be dynamic.

I have used a lot of time trying to figure this out, without any luck... I am  new to VBA coding, but I am eager to learn. I will of course give credit to good answers!

Comment: Do not use `On Error Resume Next` if you don't know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: *"...where the users of the sheet can choose a chat ID. If the user for example chooses 36..."* I believe they choose the chat Nr., not ID

Comment: Alright, but do you have any suggestions on the coding?

Comment: Thanks Tim! My mistake

Comment: Working on it yea

Comment: @Jan what is the scope of the name of the array? `Import` sheet or `Workbook`?

Comment: It is Import, Malan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code (now it will first delete output from previous runs):

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim xRng As Range
Dim oRng As Range ' Output range
Dim iWS As Worksheet, dWS As Worksheet
Dim ChatNr As Long
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long

Set iWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import")
Set dWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")
ChatNr = dWS.Cells(9, 2) ' cell B9

Set xRng = iWS.Range(dWS.Cells(18, 2).Value) ' cell B18, assuming the array name is defined in the scope of the iWS
Set oRng = dWS.Cells(6, 6) ' output in cell F6
LastRow = dWS.Cells(dWS.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
' clear previous output:
If LastRow >= 6 Then
    Range(dWS.Cells(6, 6), dWS.Cells(LastRow, 6)).ClearContents
End If
j = 0

For i = 1 To xRng.Rows.Count
    If IsError(xRng(i, 2)) = False Then ' added check for error
        If xRng(i, 2).Value = ChatNr Then
            oRng.Offset(j).Value = xRng(i, 1).Value
            j = j + 1
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Will look into this if Tim's code doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Run-time error 1004 at line: Set xRng = Range(dWS.Cells(18, 2).Value)

Comment: @Jan updated. My assumption was that the scope for names was `Workbook`. See if you still get the error. This code worked when changing the scope to `Import`.

Comment: Thanks. New error msg for the following line: If xRng(i, 2).Value = ChatNr Then

Comment: FYI, "Array1" in B18 in "Dashboard" refers to B21:C3499 in "Import". The row number will always be the same. I.e for Array2 we have N21:O3499.

Comment: @Jan updated again. I now first check that `xRng(i, 2)` doesn't contain an error value and then do the check for Chat Nr.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Make sure you backup any (critical) data before attempting any code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim i As Long, LRow As Long
Dim wb As Workbook, Import As Worksheet, Dashboard As Worksheet
Dim myArr As Variant

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set Import = wb.Sheets("Import")
Set Dashboard = wb.Sheets("Dashboard")

myArr = Import.Range(Dashboard.Range("B18").Value)
LRow = Dashboard.Cells(Dashboard.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
If LRow < 6 Then LRow = 6

For i = 1 To UBound(myArr) - 1
    If myArr(i, 2) = Dashboard.Range("B9").Value Then 
        DashBoard.Cells(LRow, "F").Value = myArr(i, 1)
        LRow = LRow + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

---

**Edit**
How to populate an array with a range

an array is basically a table stored in your PC's memory. It's useful to fill such an array with values from a range, as using arrays are often much faster than using range objects.

Populating an array with a range goes as follows:

```
Dim myArr as Variant
myArr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:B10")
```

Arrays are usually base-0, meaning the first index number is 0. With array from ranges, however, the first index number is 1, making them base-1 arrays.

Therefore, if cell `B4` holds the value `Test`, the `myArr(2,4)` holds this value as well.

However:

```
Dim myArr as Variant
myArr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:B10")
```

For the array above, the reference to cell B4's value is `myArr(2,3)` as the array was populated starting from the second row.